# how can i fix my applet making more than one button?

Tags: java, button, applet

i'm making a SUPER Tic-Tac-Toe game and everything is working fine except when the webpage is reloaded more buttons are added. i have looked around for how to fix this and i have found no fix. the error of it adding more buttons is hard to explain so the link for the applet is below. reload that page and you will see what i mean.
applet: [click here for applet page](http://foxgenesis.weebly.com/super-tic-tac-toe.html)

code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Frame extends JApplet implements ActionListener{
   /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static JFrame frame;
   public static JPanel center = new JPanel();
   public static JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
   public static JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
   public static JMenu view = new JMenu("View");
   public static JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
   public static JMenuItem newGame = new JMenuItem("New game");
   public static JCheckBoxMenuItem showColor = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Player Colors");
   public static JMenuItem helpMenu = new JMenuItem("How to Play");
   public static JMenuItem helpOpt = new JMenuItem("Options Help");
   public static JCheckBoxMenuItem ending = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Show Panel Results");
   public static JCheckBoxMenuItem ai = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Enable AI");
   public static JMenuItem playerNames = new JMenuItem("Change player names");
   public static JPanel playerIndicator = new JPanel();
   public static JTextField f1 = new JTextField(20);
   public static String player = "x";
   public static TicTacToeButtonPanel[][] bg;
   public static boolean done = false;

   public static String player1 = "Player 1";
   public static String player2 = "Player 2";

   public static TicTacToeButtonPanel selected;
   public static boolean playerMove = true;
   public static JPanel right =  new JPanel();
   public static PlayerIndecator p1 = new PlayerIndecator(player1);
   public static PlayerIndecator p2 = new PlayerIndecator(player2);
   /**
    * Called by Applet
    * Constructs basic frame and sets up game
    */
   @Override
   public void init()
   {
       this.setVisible(false);
       this.setSize(500,500);
       this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
       bg = new TicTacToeButtonPanel[3][3];
       center.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
       playerIndicator.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       helpMenu.setActionCommand("help");
       helpOpt.setActionCommand("opt");
       helpMenu.addActionListener(new Frame());
       helpOpt.addActionListener(new Frame());
       int k = 0;
       for(int i=0;i<3; i++)
           for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                   bg[i][j] = null;
                   bg[i][j] = new TicTacToeButtonPanel(k);
                   center.add(bg[i][j]);
                   newGame.addActionListener(bg[i][j]);
                   showColor.addActionListener(bg[i][j]);
                   bg[i][j].isSelected = true;
                   k++;
           }
       setJMenuBar(menu);
       menu.add(file);
       menu.add(view);
       view.add(showColor);
       view.add(ending);
       view.add(playerNames);
       menu.add(help);
       help.add(helpMenu);
       help.add(helpOpt);
       file.add(newGame);
       file.add(ai);
       right.add(p1);
       right.add(p2);
       p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1, Color.lightGray, Color.white, Color.gray, Color.lightGray));
       p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1, Color.gray,Color.white));
       p1.setBackground(Color.white);
       p2.setBackground(Color.white);
       ai.setSelected(true);
       newGame.setActionCommand("new game");
       showColor.setActionCommand("color");
       playerNames.setActionCommand("names");
       playerNames.addActionListener(new Frame());
       showColor.setSelected(true);
       ending.setSelected(true);
       add(center);
       add(right, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
       add(playerIndicator, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
       f1.setBackground(Color.white);
       playerIndicator.add(f1);
       f1.setEditable(false);
       this.setVisible(true);
       return;
   }
   @Override
   public void stop()
   {
       for(Component a: this.getContentPane().getComponents())
           this.remove(a);
   }
   @Override
   public void start()
   {
       return;
   }
   @Override
   public void destroy()
   {
       for(Component a: this.getContentPane().getComponents())
           this.remove(a);
   }
   /**
    * Check on the BIG board if a player has won or a cats game
    */
   public static void check()
   {
        checkSpace(0,0, 0,1, 0,2);
        checkSpace(1,0, 1,1, 1,2);
        checkSpace(2,0, 2,1, 2,2);
        checkSpace(0,0, 1,0, 2,0);
        checkSpace(0,1, 1,1, 2,1);
        checkSpace(0,2, 1,2, 2,2);
        checkSpace(0,0, 1,1, 2,2);
        checkSpace(0,2, 1,1, 2,0);
        checkCats();
   }
   /**
    * Used to check if a player has won the game at a location
    * @param ROW1
    * @param COLUMN1
    * @param ROW2
    * @param COLUMN2
    * @param ROW3
    * @param COLUMN3
    */
   public static void checkSpace(int ROW1, int COLUMN1, int ROW2, int COLUMN2, int ROW3, int COLUMN3)
    {
        if (bg[ROW1][COLUMN1].getOwner() == 1
            && bg[ROW2][COLUMN2].getOwner() == 1
                && bg[ROW3][COLUMN3].getOwner() == 1
                    && !done)
                        winGame(1);
        else if (bg[ROW1][COLUMN1].getOwner() == 2
            && bg[ROW2][COLUMN2].getOwner() == 2
                && bg[ROW3][COLUMN3].getOwner() == 2
                    && !done)
                        winGame(2);
    }
   /**
    * Used to check if game ends up as a cats game
    */
   public static void checkCats()
   {
       if(bg[0][0].getOwner() != 0 && bg[0][1].getOwner() != 0 
            && bg[0][2].getOwner() != 0 && bg[1][0].getOwner() != 0
                && bg[1][1].getOwner() != 0 && bg[1][2].getOwner() != 0 
                    && bg[2][0].getOwner() != 0 && bg[2][1].getOwner() != 0 
                        && bg[2][2].getOwner() != 0 && !done)
                            catsGame();
   }
   /**
    * Called by checkCats()
    * ends game and tells user that its a tie
    */
   public static void catsGame()
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame.frame ,
        "Aww! The game turned out to be \n a cats game. \n better luck next time",
        "CATS GAME!",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        done = true;
   }
   /**
    * Ends game and tells player who won
    * @param Winningplayer player who won the game
    */
   public static void winGame(int Winningplayer)
   {
       String play;
       String winPlayer;
       if(Winningplayer == 1){
            play = "x";
            winPlayer = player1;
        }
       else{
            play = "o";
            winPlayer = player2;
        }
        for(int k=0; k<3; k++)
            for(int t=0;t<3;t++)
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                    {
                        bg[k][t].board[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                        bg[k][t].isSelected = false;
                        if(showColor.isSelected() && Winningplayer == 1)bg[k][t].board[i][j].setForeground(Color.red);
                        if(showColor.isSelected() && Winningplayer == 2)bg[k][t].board[i][j].setForeground(Color.blue);
                        if(!showColor.isSelected())bg[k][t].board[i][j].setForeground(Color.black);
                        bg[k][t].board[i][j].setText(play);
                        bg[k][t].done = true;
                    }
       done = true;
       f1.setText(winPlayer + " WON THE GAME!");
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "Congradulations!\n"+
        winPlayer +"\n"+
        "YOU WON!",
        "CONGRADULATIONS!",
        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
   }
   /**
    * Basic button actions
    */
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
       if("help".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "How to play:\n"+
        "SUPER Tic-Tac-Toe is regular Tic-Tac-Toe inside Tic-Tac-Toe. \n there are 9 Tic-Tac-Toe games inside one big Tic-Tac-Toe game \n"+
        "if you win a game then you gain that panel for the big board. once the big board is won the game is over. \n Ways to tell who owns a panel: \n 1) a colored border around one of the games.\n 2) a big letter representing a player.",
        "How to play",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
       if("opt".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
       {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "Options help:\n"+
        "this game consists of 3 options: \n"+
        "located in the VIEW menu are options to change player names, turn on or off player colors, or turn on or off panel end results. \n panel end results: ON means that once a panel is won the game will stay there. \n panel end results: OFF means that once a game is won, the game will turn into a big letter representing who won. \n to change player names please enter in the names in the dialog box popup and it ok",
        "Options help",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
       }
       if("names".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
       {
           String pl1 = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
        "Player 1: ",
        "Change player names",
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        String pl2 = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
        "Player 2: ",
        "Change player names",
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        player1 = pl1;
        player2 = pl2;
        if(pl1.length() > 15)
            p1.setText(pl1.substring(0,15));
        else{
            String k = pl1;
            for(int i= pl1.length(); i < 8; i++){
                k = k + "  ";
            }
            p1.setText(k);
        }
        if(pl2.length() > 15)
            p2.setText(pl2.substring(0,15));
        else{
            String k = pl2;
            for(int i= pl2.length(); i < 8; i++){
                k = k + "  ";
            }
            p2.setText(k);
        }
        f1.setText("Names have been changed");
       }
    }
   public static void openSel()
   {
       for(int q=0; q<3; q++)
           for(int h=0; h<3; h++)
           for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                {
                    if(bg[q][h].getOwner() == 0){
                        bg[q][h].isSelected = true;
                        bg[q][h].board[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                        bg[q][h].board[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1, Color.lightGray, Color.white));
                        bg[q][h].board[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(bg[q][h].getOwner() == 1){
                            bg[q][h].board[i][j].setBackground(Color.red);
                            bg[q][h].board[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1,Color.darkGray,Color.gray));
                            bg[q][h].isSelected = false;
                        }
                        else{
                            bg[q][h].board[i][j].setBackground(Color.blue);
                            bg[q][h].board[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1,Color.darkGray,Color.gray));
                            bg[q][h].isSelected = false;
                        }
                        bg[q][h].board[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
           selected.isSelected = false;
   }
   /**
    * very important void in class!
    * changes the selected panel
    * @param panel panel to select
    */
   public static void changeSel(TicTacToeButtonPanel panel)
   {
       for(int i=0; i<3; i++)for(int j=0; j<3; j++)if(bg[i][j].isSelected)bg[i][j].isSelected = false;
       selected = panel;
       panel.isSelected = true;
       for(int q=0; q<3; q++)
       for(int h=0; h<3; h++)
       {
           if(selected.getOwner() != 0)
           {
               openSel();

           }
           else if(!bg[q][h].isSelected && bg[q][h].getOwner() == 0)
           {
               for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                {
                    bg[q][h].board[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                    bg[q][h].board[i][j].setBackground(Color.gray);
                    bg[q][h].board[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1,Color.darkGray,Color.gray));
                }
           }
           else if(bg[q][h].isSelected && bg[q][h].getOwner() == 0)
           {
               for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                {
                    bg[q][h].board[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                    bg[q][h].board[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                    bg[q][h].board[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1, Color.lightGray, Color.white));
                }
           }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Frame.class wasn't found when I clicked on your link.

Comment: umm it works on every other computer i use it with. there is a link on that page to download the applet jar file. try downloading it and running it from your computer. the main class is in default package and is called Frame.class

Comment: If components are removed in the `stop` method, they should be added in the `start` method.